# How to pass form fields into 'templated' HTML file

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I would like to get form data from a pre-built HTML template using a Django form without changing the display.

I know I could use something like:

```
name = request.POST.get('first_name')
```

But would like to handle the data using a ModelForm

#### forms.py

```
class BioDataForm(forms.ModelForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='first_name')
    last_name =forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='last_name')
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='mobile_number')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, label='personal_email')
    gender = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'gender'}))
    marital_status = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'marital_status'}))
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'], widget=forms.SelectDateWidget())
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = BioData
        exclude = ('state',)
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile', 'email',
                'gender', 'marital_status', 'date_of_birth', 'address']
```

#### Sample HTML

```
<div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 margin-bottom-20-m">
       <label for="first_name" class="form-control-label kt-black-text">First Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="e_first_name" required>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <label for="last_name" class="form-control-label kt-black-text">Last Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="e_last_name" required>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can replace the `input` tags by **{{form.field_name}}**. For example, **{{ form.first_name }}** instead of **<input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="e_first_name" required>**. Also, add widget classes to the form fields to make sure the input fields appear as they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

iterate form in template :

```
<div class="row form-group">
   {% for field in form %}
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 margin-bottom-20-m">
       <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="form-control-label kt-black-text">{{ field.label }}</label>
       {{ field }}
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```